# (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults..... Querying Athena From Lambda Python.... Cannot Read Results

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-athena, python-3.8

I have been trying to query Athena from my lambda function (Python3.8) but I keep getting the same error although tried adding an if else statement to check the status of the execution and i always the same error on the aws console and the cli locally

Here is the lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3
import time

def function(event, context):
    client=boto3.client('athena')

    #setup and perform query
    queryStart=client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = 'SELECT * FROM my_s3_bucket_developer limit 8;',
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            'Database':'mydb'
        },
        ResultConfiguration = {
            'OutputLocation': 's3://athena-results-queries-developer/'
        }
    ) 
    
    #get query ID
    queryId= queryStart['QueryExecutionId']

    #we gonna sleep the function now because we don't know how 
    #long it will take to execute the query
    time.sleep(25)

    results=client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId)
    for row in results['ResultSet']['Rows']:
        print(row)
```

and this is the IAM Role I have attached to my lambda function:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "S3:GetBucketLocation",
                "S3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::athena-results-queries-developer/*",
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                "athena:StopQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetQueryExecution",
                "athena:GetQueryResults",
                "glue:GetTable"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error I keep getting in the logs

> An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults operation: Query did not finish successfully. Final query state: FAILED
>
> "errorType": "InvalidRequestException"
>
> "stackTrace": [
> [
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
> 26,
> "function",
> "results=client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId = queryId)"
> ],
> [
> "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
> 316,
> "_api_call",
> "return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)"
> ],
> [
> "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
> 626,
> "_make_api_call",
> "raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)"
> ]
> ]
> }

If anyone can help me would really appreciate it - I have been trying to solve this for days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you don't wait for the query to complete properly. You need to call `get_query_execution` and check that the query has succeeded before you call `get_query_results`.

There's a full example here that you could take inspiration from: https://www.ilkkapeltola.fi/2018/04/simple-way-to-query-amazon-athena-in.html

Comment: thank you so much man you save me a lot of time all i added to the code was this line before get_query_results() ```results=client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId = queryId)```

Comment: I adapted this to run and then check on a list of queries. Worked great!