# InvalidRequestException upon using get_query_results despite getting HTTPStatusCode: 200 when I ran start_query_execution previously

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, boto3, amazon-athena

I am trying to execute an AWS Athena query in my Jupyter notebook and also retrieve the results using Boto3.

I first ran this to execute my query:

```
response1 = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString= "SELECT date from my data_table LIMIT 1;",
    QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': 'my_database',
        'Catalog': 'AwsDataCatalog'
    },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': 's3://XXX/YYY/'
        
    }
)
```

The resultant output of the response is:

```
{'QueryExecutionId': 'abcd123456',
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'efgh123456',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
   'date': 'Mon, 05 Jul 2021 06:38:15 GMT',
   'x-amzn-requestid': 'ijklmn123456',
   'content-length': '59',
   'connection': 'keep-alive'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Next, I wanted to retrieve the results using the QueryExecutionId which is 'abcd123456' obtained above as shown below:

```
response2 = client.get_query_results(
    QueryExecutionId = 'abcd123456',
    MaxResults = 123
)
```

However, it throws me this error:

```
InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults operation: Query did not finish successfully. Final query state: FAILED
```

I wonder why does it say final query state is 'FAILED' when the HTTPStatusCode of the start_query_execution is 200. I did refer to this link [(InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults..... Querying Athena From Lambda Python.... Cannot Read Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62767533/invalidrequestexception-when-calling-the-getqueryresults-querying-athena) but I couldn't solve my problem.

Would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can run the query and obtain the results when I changed my s3 output location. I guess I had limited permission to the previous s3 bucket path I used.